# Find and tag const variables and const functions in C++

Tags: c++, code-cleanup

I have a large C++ code base ( 500,000+ LOC, 10k files ) and I'm happy with the code but there are several problems with it:

const hasn't been used as much as it should.  For example:

```
class A
{
  int foo( B &a )
  {
    return a.v * 10;
  }
};
```

should really be changed to:

```
class A
{
  int foo( const B &a )  const
  {
    return a.v * 10;
  }
};
```

It seems like the compiler should know, in most cases, when a function could be const.

It has also been written in standard C++ as of the early 2000s.  I would like to change to use auto and for range loops so

```
 std::map< int, std::string >::iterator i = m.start();
 for ( ; i != m.end(); i++
   ...;
```

to

```
for ( const auto p : m )
  ...;
```

I could hack something together with perl and/or sed that would probably find most of the cases because the code conforms closely to our internal standards but I'm just wondering if there is a real tool out there that will do this and other things that we may want to do?  How do you migrate legacy C++ code to a new standard?

Comment: Don't use int foo( const int &a ), just int foo(int a).

Comment: Don't change what isn't broken...

Comment: I _highly_ recommend not doing the loop bit automatically.  There's a lot of loops where you actually need iterators for various reasons.

Comment: Yeah, the loop syntax part might be a little hairy. If you have any loops that need to erase elements while iterating through a container you are pretty much forced to use iterator syntax over range based for loops.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The cases when you actually need the iterator are pretty easy to detect, you have `it` appear inside the body in some form other than `*it` or `it->`  It's more difficult to decide between `auto elem`, `auto& elem`, or `auto const& elem`.

Comment: Note that automated detection and suggestion is useful, but you don't want automated changes without a set of skilled eyes approving or rejecting each change.  Applying this blindly will make code less generic.

Comment: I'm not sure `foo` should be a member function of `A` at all. If it is, it should be `static`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find C++ functions that should be const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539590/how-can-i-find-c-functions-that-should-be-const)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be a great opportunity to use [ReSharper for C++](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/cpp.html) in case your code is organized into Visual Studio solution. It is still in development but thanks to this fact it is **free**.

It contains a lot of built in code inspections and you can perform solution wide code cleanup. I use its C# version on daily basis and while C++ version has still lots to catch up it seems to be a suitable tool for your situation.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know of anything similar for the Linux world?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.